# When is this function integrable ? polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, polar-coordinates, singularity

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I'm interested in for what $k$ the function $\frac{1}{1+\|\cdot\|}f_{k}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\partial_{x_{i}}f_{k}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Where $f_k:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is defined as

$$
f_k(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|^k}. 
$$

If this is too much to ask then a simpler thing to ask ( which Im still interested in) is for what $k$ is $f_k\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

---

---

---

$\textbf{Note : }$ (since the function looks radial) I tried to use polar coordinates (assuming $d$ is even)  : $(x_i,x_j)=r_i(\cos \theta_i,\sin \theta_i)$ with $r_i\in \mathbb{R}_+,\theta_i\in [0,2\pi)$, so that $$dx=\prod_i r_idrd\theta$$

and

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^{d/2} \times [0,2\pi]^{d/2}}\big|\big(f(r,\theta)\big)_i\big|\prod_i r_idrd\theta =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{| r_i \cos \theta_i |}{\|r\|^{k}} \prod_i r_idrd\theta $$

then I was thinking of using that $\Big(\prod_i r_i\Big)^{2/d}\leq \frac{2}{d}\sum_i^{d/2} r_i$ but im really not sure where im going with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how polar coordinates work in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Their construction is rather difficult and [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelkoordinaten#Verallgemeinerung_auf_n-dimensionale_Kugelkoordinaten) should give you a nice impression. You could also use the coarea formula that states
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u(x)~\mathrm{d}x = \int^\infty_0\int_{\partial B_r(0)} u(x)~\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)~\mathrm{d}r
$$
for $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

The important takeaway from this should be that there exists some constant $C >0 $ (that is some integral over a finite product of $\sin$ and $\cos$ that you get in the numerator when you pass to polar coordinates) such that:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{\lvert x_j \rvert}{(1+\lVert x \rVert)\lVert x \rVert^k}~\mathrm{d}x = C\int^\infty_0 \frac{r}{(1+r)r^k} \underbrace{r^{d-1}}_{\text{Jacobian}}~\mathrm{d}r = C\int^\infty_0 \frac{r^{d-k}}{1+r}~\mathrm{d}r
$$
This does never converge.

Nothing stops you from applying this reasoning to the derivative, too.

Comment: aha ok ok, interesting. Can I ask when you used Coarea formula you mean $u(x(r,\sigma))$. Funny how the link your provided is on the German wiki xd.  What is this kind of math called ? Are these types of integrals (and their relation say to PDE/ODE) discussed well in any textbook you know of?

Comment: No, i mean $u(x)$ in a cartesian sense. With $\sigma$ I usually denote the surface integral by $\sigma$ and I clarified it in the response. The link is in german because I am german :D. I have not really seen them in textbooks, but I think you might have to look up textbooks on Sobolev spaces (and or functional analysis).  I do not know if there is a specific name for this except for vector calculus. But in the theory of Sobolev spaces, radial integrals (e.g. $\int_{B_1(0)} \log\lvert \log \lVert x \rVert \rvert~\mathrm{d}x$) often occur to disprove certain embeddings of Sobolev-spaces.

Comment: why does changing to polar coordinates help us so much in seeing if these type of singular functions are integrable ?

Comment: Also are you sure about your conclusion of converging integral?

Comment: It helps, because those functions are symmetrical in a ball-sense. So you can break it down to the one-dimensional case by just considering the radius of that ball. Yes I am rather sure. Do you have any objections?

Comment: wolfram alpha $r^{(-2)}/(1+r)$ on 0 to infinity ?

Comment: Oh riiiiight... . I forgot about the singularity in $0$. I will have to reconsider this...

Comment: Doesn't look like it converges at all...

Comment: True, it can't converge